# How to sum $\frac{1}{(3n+2)(3n+3)}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

Is there analytic way of summing this series? (I have used Wolfram)

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{(3n+2)(3n+3)}=\dfrac{1}{18}\left(9\log(3)-\sqrt{3}\pi\right)$$

If I decompose it, it is going to be $\dfrac{1}{3n+2}-\dfrac{1}{3(n+1)}$. I don't think this is a telescopic series.

If I convert this into integration, then I will have

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(3n+2)(3n+3)}=\dfrac{1}{3}\log(\dfrac{3}{2})$$

Can I use a power series to sum this? I don't think it is easy to find a power series, and even if we can, we cannot easily find the limiting function to which this series converge.

Comment: This can be evaluated via the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Comment: @lulu can you post a full answer, if your answer is easy to understand to me, I will upvote you. :)

Comment: The link I gave provides a step by step procedure for evaluating expressions of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {p(n)}{q(n)}$, for polynomials $p,q$.  Just follow those steps.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(3n+2)(3n+3)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1(x^{3n+1}-x^{3n+2})\,dx=\int_0^1\frac{x-x^2}{1-x^3}\,dx=\int_0^1\frac{x\,dx}{1+x+x^2}.$$

Comment: @metamorphy how do you convert so fast the infinite sum into the integral. This is something that completely lie outside of my ability. Please post a full answer, if I can understand, I will upvote you.

Comment: @JamesWarthington there was no conversion. $\int_0^1 (x^{3n+1} - x^{3n+2}) = \frac{1}{(3n+2)(3n+3)}$. Then sum both sides. and exchange the summation and the integral. What remains to sum is an infinte geometric progression.

Comment: @Whyareyoureadingmyname Well, how do you know? I have seen this in other posts asked by other members but I don't know how to derive the integral from the sum.

Comment: @JamesWarthington It follows from your partial fraction decomposition and the fact that $\int x^k\,dx=\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}+C$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it as follows:\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(3n+2)(3n+3)}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{3n+2}-\frac1{3n+3}\right)\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1x^{3n+1}-x^{3n+2}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1x^{3n}(x-x^2)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{3n}(x-x^2)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^1\frac{x-x^2}{1-x^3}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^1\frac x{x^2+x+1}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\frac12\left(\int_0^1\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+1}\,\mathrm dx-\int_0^1\frac1{\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}\,\mathrm dx\right)\\&=\log\left(\sqrt3\right)-\frac\pi{6\sqrt3}.\end{align}

Comment: Why your final answer looks different from that of Wolfie? :)

Comment: If I [ask WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F%28%283n%2B2%29%283n%2B3%29%29+with+n+from+0+to+infinity), I get$$\frac1{18}\left(9\log(3)-\sqrt3\pi\right),$$which is the same value as the one that I got.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I should have been more careful. There is no difference.

Comment: How did you move from:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(3n+2)(3n+3)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{3n+2}-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{3n+3}$$

to

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1x^{3n+1}-x^{3n+2}dx$$]

I don't understand how did you turn the sum into the integral. Also how do you know the upperbound is $1$

Comment: At no point I wrote that$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(3n+2)(3n+3)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{3n+2}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{3n+3}.$$That makes no sense, since those two series on the RHS diverge. What I wrote was that$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(3n+2)(3n+3)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{3n+2}-\frac1{3n+3}.$$Now, just use that fact that$$\int_0^1x^k\,\mathrm dx=\left[\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}\right]_{x=0}^{x=1}=\frac1{k+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks, I understand, but how did you know that the upper bound of the integral is $1$?

Comment: I did not **know** that. I wanted to express $\frac1{3n+2}$ and $\frac1{3n+3}$ as integrals and I thought that the natural way of doing it would be to write them as $\int_0^1x^{3n+1}\,\mathrm dx$ and as $\int_0^1x^{3n+2}\,\mathrm dx$ respectively.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. My last question is how do you move from this to this: \begin{align}\mathrm\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1x^{3n}(x-x^2)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^1\frac{x-x^2}{1-x^3}\,\mathrm dx\\&\end{align}

Comment: How do you sum the integral and return a definite integral?

Comment: By doing:\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1x^{3n}(x-x^2)\,\mathrm dx&=\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty(x^3)^n\right)(x-x^2)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^1\frac{x-x^2}{1-x^3}\,\mathrm dx.\end{align}

Comment: The $\dfrac{1}{1-x^3}$ is a geometric series, I got it now. Interchanging summation and integration is justfied because the lower bound is 0, am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119508/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-james-warthington).